# jQuery - Form Validation with tabs outside of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [FormValidation plugin for jQuery](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/) - and I am trying to create a form wizard using the `bootstrap tabs`. This is my code so far:

```
<form class="center-form" id="installationForm" method="post">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <! -- #tab1 -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="details">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="ad-title form-control" name="title" value="" placeholder="Enter your advertisement title...">
            </div>

        </div>
        <! -- #tab1 end -->
        <! -- #tab2 -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="audience">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="ad-title form-control" name="description" value="" placeholder="Enter your advertisement title...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <! -- #tab2 end -->

    </div>
    <ul class="pager wizard">
        <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Previous</a>

        </li>
        <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs ad-creation" id="progress">
        <li class="active"> <a href="#details" data-toggle="tab" class="button btn-round">tab1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#audience" data-toggle="tab" class="button btn-round">tab2</a></li>
```

And my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#installationForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            // This option will not ignore invisible fields which belong to inactive panels
            excluded: ':disabled',
            fields: {
                name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The site name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                url: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The URL is required'
                        },
                        uri: {
                            message: 'The URL is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .bootstrapWizard({
            tabClass: 'nav nav-pills',
            onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                return validateTab(index);
            },
            onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                var numTabs    = $('#progress').find('.tab-pane').length,
                    isValidTab = validateTab(index - 1);
                if (!isValidTab) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (index === numTabs) {
                    // We are at the last tab

                }

                return true;
            },
            onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                return validateTab(index + 1);
            },
            onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                // Update the label of Next button when we are at the last tab
                var numTabs = $('#progress').find('.tab-pane').length;
                $('#installationForm')
                    .find('.next')
                        .removeClass('disabled')    // Enable the Next button
                        .find('a')
                        .html(index === numTabs - 1 ? 'Install' : 'Next');

            }
        });

    function validateTab(index) {
        var fv   = $('#installationForm').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
            // The current tab
            $tab = $('#installationForm').find('.tab-pane').eq(index);

        // Validate the container
        fv.validateContainer($tab);

        var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($tab);
        if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
            // Do not jump to the target tab
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Now - the validation works **IF** I move the `#progress` inside the `#installionForm` form tag.

My question is how can I get it to validate the form fields inside the tabs, **and** have the `#progress` moved out of the `#installationForm`?

Comment: Validation only works if the item is visible, but you can turn this feature off so it will validate all on the page whether hidden or not - the docs explain how

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't test but have you tried creating/using another element wrapped around the form and the #progress(is outside form but inside new element).

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've been looking at their website for the past 3 hours - still can't find anything about this. Do you have a reference or link?

Comment: @Kepoly Good thinking! Although it didn't work. Not sure if the #element has to be a <form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow validation when fields are hidden we must override the default ignore while hidden.

This should work for you:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    ignore: [],
    // etc etc other validation options
});
```

The validation code looks at the code and basically creates an array of fields to ignore, this overrides with an empty array, meaning validate all.

Comment: I am not quite sure on how to use that function. I don't have any hidden fields. I just wish to place my `#progress ul` outside of the  `#installationForm` div.